# Sending a variable to a function expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I will begin by explaining what I am trying to do here with a simple example.

1. Create a local scope variable *id* and give it a value *x*.
2. Create a function expression where I print out the value *x* by means of *alert(a);* and store that function as a variable *fn* in a global list.
3. Modify *id* to represent the value *y*.
4. Call *fn();* through my global list and have *x* printed out for me.

The problem now is that the value printed by *fn()* is *y* and not *x* as was initially assigned to *id*. I first found a solution by dealing with temporary global variables, but it simply doesn't work anymore as the project has grown quite a bit. I no longer have the means required to keep track of these global temps.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. I apology if this question has been answered before. Perhaps I am just not very good at searching the web, but I have yet to find a satisfying one.

Note: I should perhaps add that contrary to the amount of times I mentioned the variable scopes, it is not a problem. The local variable seems to somehow be treated globally (or perhaps a global pointer to it is created?) as there is no problem printing a local variable from other scopes when done in the manner described above.

Here is a code sample of what I want (I decided it would be clearer this way than using my own code):

```
var fnList = []
function FunctionA(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var iToFunctionExpression = i; // this is where I want to somehow send my variable to the function
        fnList.push(function(){
            alert(iToFunctionExpression);
        });
    }
}
function FunctionB(){
    for(var i = 10; i < 20; i++){
        var iToFunctionExpression = i; // this is where I want to somehow send my variable to the function
        fnList.push(function(){
            alert(iToFunctionExpression);
        });
    }
}
function FunctionPrintAB(){
    for(var fn = 0; fn < fnList.length; fn++){
        fnList[fn](); // here I want to alert the numbers 0 through 19
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: you are looking for the term "closure"

Comment: Could you explain what you are referring to by "my global list"?  Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far.  I don't follow from your words exactly what you're trying to accomplish or what you really need help with.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy A list in the global scope containing a bunch of functions. Added a code example to clarify what I want.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a closure:

```
var x = 1;

function makealerter(i) {
    return function() {
        alert(i);
    }
}

var fn = makealerter(x);

var y = 2;

fn();

x = y;

fn();
```

Comment: Never even encountered the term in this regard before. Well, thank you, this does the job!